# Confused by CaretOffset/LanguageItem methods

Tags: xamarin-studio

I am trying to find out over which source file element the cursor is located (code is inside a pad)

```
//Obtain document
Document sf = IdeApp.Workbench.ActiveDocument;
//out argument
DocumentRegion dr;

//Call using offset
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISymbol o = sf.GetLanguageItem(sf.Editor.CaretOffset  , out dr);
```

The ISymbol returned "o" is Object's Equals. The document sf is a simple class with a parameterless constructor. The cursor is inside the constructor. I was expecting my class constructor.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found a work around to get context data out of the current editor caret offset. It requires to obtain AnalysisDocument from the current document, then the SemanticModel of the document and after obtaining this model, calling GetEnclosingSymbol with the caret offset.